# spotfire : how to calculate a percentage of data of one column from the total of another column

Tags: percentage, spotfire

I want to sort the customer reviews from the following file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cgVc.png)
I want to get a pareto with the percentage of comments compared to the number of customers.
for example: 2 comments are about noise
this represents 40% of the customers

I can obtain the percentage in relation to the number of comments (25%) by using the following formula on the value axis
Count([ref_comments]) THEN [Value] / sum([Value]) OVER (All([Axis.X]))

but I can't find the formula to get the 40%

all your feedback will be useful to me
thank you in advance

Comment: I am guessing you mean a bar chart. What is the category axis?

Comment: yes exactly ! the category axis is the type_comment

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the numbers you want, you could try:

```
UniqueCount(If([nb_comments]>0,[customer],null)) / UniqueCount([customer]) OVER (All([Axis.X]))
```

I understand you want to count the customers who *did* comment, but compare to *all* available customers.
So you are dealing with 4 customers who did comment, but 5 overall customers.
I put the if(..) statement to remove the non-responders from the numerator, but included all
in the denominator.

An alternative formula could be:

```
UniqueCount([customer]) / UniqueCount([customer]) OVER (All([Axis.X]))
```

you would need *also* to Limit data by expression:  [nb_comments]>0.

This however would give you 50% for sound instead, as half of the customer who responded commented about sound.

Comment: I'm going to try, thank you !

Comment: by limiting data with [nb_comments]>0, it excludes the customer3 : I don't find the rate of 40% = number of sound (2) divided by number of customers (5)

Comment: yes the second method gives you a different result. The first method gives you the result you wanted. I was simply wondering why you want to normalize with all the customers and not just with the customers who responded. So if you want 40% use the first method and do not use the limit expression (that was only for the alternative method)

Comment: I tried the fisrt method with :
Approx_Count_Distinct (If([nb_comments]>0,[customer],null)) / Approx_Count_Distinct([customer]) OVER (All([Axis.X]))   because the UniqueCount function isn't found, and then it's the All function that can't be found

Comment: is your data from a database or other non-file connection? You might have different sets of functions available to you. But in your original question you do use All so why is it not found now?

Comment: This is the info I found: Not all of the standard Spotfire aggregation methods and expressions are available on all external systems. On the other hand, there may be other methods available that Spotfire does not have by default.
 The aggregation methods supported by the external data source determines which methods will be available for in-database data. So if your data comes from a specific data source, I cannot reproduce or test your case.